# Cassandra UDT VerifierMappingExceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am developing spring boot application. it connects Apache Cassandra DB. I have created UDT in Cassandra. while trying to save data using CassandraOperations. I am  getting exception.  I have followed below example for Cassandra UDT.

http://www.devjavasource.com/cassandra/cassandra-udts-java-example/

**Cassandra DB**: 2.1.11

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: com.lab.model.OrderLine:
Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:45) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

OrderLine java class has only @UDT not @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;


@Table("order")
public class Order {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "ord_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
     private int ord_id;
     private List<OrderLine> order_line;  

}


import java.util.UUID;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.UDT;
@UDT(name = "order_line")
public class OrderLine {

    private UUID po_line_nbr;
    private int whpk_qty;
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Cassandra does not support Datastax' mapping annotations.

UDT support for Spring Data Cassandra is about to get merged with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/84.

You will be able to specify UDT's with `@UserDefinedType` and to use `UDTValue`

```
@UserDefinedType
public class Address {
  String city;
  String country;
}

@Table
public class Person {

  @Id String id;
  Address address;
  UDTValue genericUdt;
}
```

Expect Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 to be released end of this year (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls)

Comment: I am not able to find suitable dependency. I have updated pom.xml. could you please correct my pom.xml to fix my issue. thanks

Comment: UDT support is not yet available as `SNAPSHOT` built.

Comment: is it possible to develop spring with Cassandra on UDT ? or not possible. could you please help me on this ?. I am new to spring with Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

I have used Mapper concept. it is working good. I have followed below URLs to resolve my issue.

```
https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.1.7/features/object_mapper/using/

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-590
```